# self.navigationController is nil in swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have 6 to 7 viewControllers in my storyBoard and in this view controller I get  self.navigationController as nil but works every where else . I've done the same thing every other place but this one doesn't work. I couldn't figure out why? 
    import UIKit

```
class wkScreen2ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {



    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 500
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        //        tableView.scrollEnabled = true

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return 3
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
        UITableViewCell {


            if(indexPath.row == 0){
            var cell: Cell1TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1") as Cell1TableViewCell

            return cell
            }

            if(indexPath.row == 1){
                println("2")
                var cell: Cell2TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2") as Cell2TableViewCell

                return cell
            }

            if(indexPath.row == 2){
                println("3")
                var cell: Cell3TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell3") as Cell3TableViewCell

                return cell
            }


           return UITableViewCell()

    }
    func navigateTowkScreen3(){
        println("next2")
            let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            var wkScr3 = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("wkScreen3") as wkScreen3ViewController
        println(wkScr3)
        println(self.navigationController)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(wkScr3, animated: true)


    }



}
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0q7whsgiq3nw14e/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-10%20at%203.39.06%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Are you certain it has a navigation controller? Not all view controllers do.

Comment: How to be sure if it has the navigation controller , guess this is a rookie question but I kinda did the same thing with this view controller as o did for the others

Comment: Well, in the storyboard does it have a navigation controller in there? If so, what is the segue type that is going into this controller? (Can you show a screenshot of the storyboard?)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0q7whsgiq3nw14e/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-10%20at%203.39.06%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: this is the screen shot . The navigation controller is nil for wkScreen2ViewController

Comment: As you can see in there. WalkThrough controller and WK2 controller are not connected to the navigation controller. So they will not have a navigation controller.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tgj7eupy7s3sxus/Screenshot%202014-12-10%2015.46.04.png?dl=0

Comment: so WalkThroughController is not connected but self.navigationController is not nil for that

Comment: var wkScr2 = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("wkScreen2") as wkScreen2ViewController
       println(self.navigationController)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(wkScr2, animated: true)

Comment: Yes, but how are you presenting it. If you are presenting it from registration view controller using `[self.navigationController push...` then it will use the same navigation controller.

Comment: Why are you not just using segues?

Comment: var wkScr2 = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("wkScreen2") as wkScreen2ViewController
       println(self.navigationController)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(wkScr2, animated: true)

Comment: I'm doing this from the walkthroughScreen1ViewContorller and it is not nil and on hitting next in walkthroughScreen1 it is navigating to wkScreen2

Comment: Why are you not just using segues?

Comment: coz I need to do some validations on the nexbutton

Comment: You can still use a segue though. Just use a segue that you run programatically.

Comment: could you show me how to do it.. I just started learning swift and building an app at the same time , and I have no idea what obj-c is

Comment: OK, will add an answer.

Comment: thanks appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is to use a segue.

You said you wanted to check on a condition when the next button is pressed before actually going to the next screen though.

So, you first need to add the segue. But instead of adding it from the Next button to the view controller you need to add it from the first view controller (little yellow box) to the second view controller.

Like this...

[image]

Then give the segue an identifier like `WalkThrough1Segue`.

Now if your code you will have your next button function like this...

```
func navigateTowkScreen3() {
    // first check your condition
    if (/*some condition*/) {
        // trigger the segue
        performSegueWithIdentifier("WalkThrough1Segue")
    }
}
```