# UINavigationController returning nil

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, uistoryboardsegue

we already have same questions where `UINavigationController` is returning `nil` but they all are related to segues's like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406699/self-navigationcontroller-is-nil-in-swift) but mine question is a bit different :

in my TableViewController i embedded a `UINavigationController` and from my tableView I'm opening another ViewController (in this viewController `navigationController` is nil)

MY STORYBOARD :
[image]

The strange is thing is that if i select first or last row of my tableView everything works fine (navigationController does not returns nil) but when i select any other row it returns nil

I'm using navigationBar in `ViewWillAppear` and `ScrollViewDidScroll`  :

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    hairLine.hidden = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
    self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

}
```

Do anybody knows whats wrong here ?

Comment: First go and delete segue from your storyborad now write method for pushing view in "didSelectRowForIndexPath" delegate method of tableview.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS already done that man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have joined the segue directly from prototype cell instead of viewcontroller. Join segue betwween controller to controller not from any UI component. Override `prepareForSegue` method.

Comment: hey man i tried as you suggested but still navigationController is nil

Comment: what you have write in didselect method of tableview?

Comment: `performSegueWithIdentifier("openTag", sender: self)`

Comment: Have you checked your segue connection in storyboard?